# Я хочу привязать свое приложение к базе данных MySql

Tags: mysql, android-studio, xampp

Я написал код , но когда я загружаю приложениее на смартфон , оно пишет : failed to connect: 127.0.0.1//*** что делать ? код: 
И нужен ли мне свой сервер (как его создать )
    package com.example.faiizii.mysqltest;

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by faiizii on 11-Feb-18.
 */

public class background extends AsyncTask <String, Void,String> {

    AlertDialog dialog;
    Context context;
    public Boolean login = false;
    public background(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        dialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        dialog.setMessage(s);
        dialog.show();
        if(s.contains("login successful"))
        {
            Intent intent_name = new Intent();
            intent_name.setClass(context.getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent_name);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
        String result = "";
        String user = voids[0];
        String pass = voids[1];

        String connstr = "http://yourIPhere:8080/login.php";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(connstr);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setDoInput(true);
            http.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream ops = http.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ops,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user,"UTF-8")
                    +"&&"+URLEncoder.encode("pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pass,"UTF-8");
            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            ops.close();

            InputStream ips = http.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"ISO-8859-1"));
            String line ="";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result += line;
            }
            reader.close();
            ips.close();
            http.disconnect();
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            result = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = e.getMessage();
        }


        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: А код, который Вы написали Вы не могли бы приложить к вопросу? И что значит "привязать своё приложение к базе данных MySQL"?.. я не слышал, чтобы MySQL выпускал сборки для Android'а (может, конечно, я слишком старый). Может Вы при разработке подключались к Базе Данных, которая была расположена на компьютере, на котором Вы ведёте разработку?

Comment: код добавил , извините за непонятный вопрос , да я хочу подключится к базе данных

Comment: *`String connstr = "http://yourIPhere:8080/login.php";`* Вот тут должен быть указан правильный реальный IP. А в коде login.php (или подключаемого к нему модуля) - соответственно правильный IP (уже с точки зрения PHP-сервера) MySQL-сервера.

Comment: пробовал,ставил ipv4,127.0.0.1  не помогло

Comment: @ChingizK, `127.0.0.1` - это адрес текущей машины. Он всегда зарезервирован, для того чтобы передавать данные на текущем компьютере. Соответственно, находясь на рабочей станции Вы будете по этому обращаться к этой же рабочей станции, а находясь на мобильном устройстве, по данному адресу будет - мобильное устройство. Это ссылка на самого себя.

Comment: так что мне делать ?